# How to grep for a single quote?

Tags: grep

I am grepping through some VB source files. I use the following query -

```
     grep -nr "GlobalCommArea\s*=\s*.*\.Transaction" .
```

Some of the lines, however, are commented and begin with a single line comment. A single line comment in VB starts with a single quote - '

Unfortunately, I cannot simply remove all those lines that have a single quote in them, because some of the lines have a single quote comment after the line of code.

So I tried something like this to remove the single quote at the start of the line

```
     grep -nr "GlobalCommArea\s*=\s*.*\.Transaction" . | grep -v "^\s*'"
```

However, this did not work. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `grep -n` which prefixes matches with line numbers, so your second pattern `"^\s*'"` will never match.  Instead, you can use one single regex:

```
grep -nr "^[^']*GlobalCommArea\s*=\s*.*\.Transaction" .
```

This searches for instances of your pattern not preceded by any single quotes.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure grep does not support `\s` to mean whitespace.

Comment: @bonsaiviking The OP is probably using GNU `grep`, which does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake! After seeing your post, I was also able to achieve this with  grep -nr "GlobalCommArea\s*=\s*.*\.Transaction" . | grep -v "^.*:[[:digit:]]*:\s*'"

Comment: Hey, but your solution doesn't actually work. The comments remain. I tried it.

Comment: @jw013 It still gives me those lines that begin with a single quote or with some whitespace and then a single quote.

Comment: @CodeBlue oh right I forgot the `^` anchor at the beginning.  Fixed.

Comment: @jw013 Source dive shows that feature was added in a later version than 2.5.4, which is what I have on Ubuntu 10.04. FYI

Comment: @jw013 What is the technical term for this ^[^'] syntax that you used?

Comment: @CodeBlue The first `^` is an [anchor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08) while the `[^']` is a [bracket expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05).

Comment: @bonsaiviking Good to know.  It was definitely added in 2.6, but `[[:space:]]` is equivalent and more portable anyways.